# Unable to use "Filter" in AWS Rest API request

Tags: python, rest, api, amazon-web-services

I am trying to use "Filter" in request parameters while sending REST API request to AWS. Surprisingly, below request parameter just works:

request_parameters = 'Action=DescribeAvailabilityZones&Version=2016-11-15'

However, as soon as I change it to:
request_parameters = 'Action=DescribeAvailabilityZones&**Filter.1.state=available**&Version=2016-11-15'

I get, "The parameter state is not recognized"

I am picking up the Filter's syntax from [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeAvailabilityZones.html)

Any suggestions please? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

figured out the solution. The parameters list expects the filter to be passed in a key/value fashion. Below is the amendment which I found to be working:

request_parameters = 'Action=DescribeAvailabilityZones&**Filter.1.Name=state**&**Filter.1.Value=available**&Version=2016-11-15'

I also noticed that unless this option is present in the list of recognized filters, it wont work. This can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html) under specific Actions.

Also, filters tags bear relation with tags in XML response. for e.g. the filter to list state of an AvailabilityZone is "state" but in the XML response it is tagged as `<zoneState>`.